# SemanticUI dropdown menu does not pick up menu items dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, webforms, semantic-ui

I have a requirement to display state names based on the selected country using the semantic dropdown. So, I am using separate asp: DropDownList for country and state in the background to fetch the data from the database. On Page_Load(), I construct the menu items in the backend code as an HTML string for the semantic dropdown to load and display the menu items. It works fine each time I change the country. But each time the entire page is reloaded which does not feel good.

Now, I am trying to refresh only the state dropdown(Semantic dropdown) without reloading the page.
Hence, I have placed the asp: dropdownlist controls in an asp: UpdatePanel to do the partial rendering of the page. But when I change the country, the state dropdown does not pick the updated values loaded in the UpdatePanel.
While debugging, I could see the state values updated in the asp dropdown and the HTML string in the backend.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Country Dropdown and sql data source-->
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCountry" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:.......%>"
            SelectCommand="......." SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="......"
            DataTextField="CountryName" DataValueField="CountryCode" Style="display: none">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <!-- State Dropdown and sql data source-->
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceState" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:..... %>"
            SelectCommand=".........." SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="......" Name="EnterCountryCode" PropertyName="......." Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListState" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="......" DataTextField="....." DataValueField="......" Style="display: none">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<div id="dvIDCountryCodeDropdownClone" class="ui selection dropdown dvDropDownCountry">
     <input type="hidden" name="countryDropdown">
     <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
     <%=strClsCountryNameHTML%>
</div>
<div id="dvIDStateCodeDropdownClone" class="ui selection dropdown dvStateCityDropDown">
    <input type="hidden" name="stateDropdown">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <%=strClsStateNameHTML%>
</div>
```

Here is the script to initialize the drop-down

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dvIDCountryCodeDropdownClone').dropdown();
    $('#dvIDStateCodeDropdownClone').dropdown();
</script>
```

I tried this initialization in pageLoad() as well, but it did not work.
I searched the articled and tried the options suggested such as initializing the dropdown once again, (.ui.dropdown).dropdown("refresh") etc. Nothing solved the issue.

Can anyone give me some ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanel does an ajax and updates only the components and elements that are inside it that have an ID and `runat="server"`.

Do something like that:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        // SqlDataSources and DropDownLists

        <div id="dvIDCountryCodeDropdownClone" class="ui selection dropdown dvDropDownCountry">
            <input type="hidden" name="countryDropdown">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div id="countryDropdown" class="menu" runat="server" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dvIDStateCodeDropdownClone" class="ui selection dropdown dvStateCityDropDown">
            <input type="hidden" name="stateDropdown">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div id="stateDropdown" class="menu" runat="server" >
            </div>
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

> Do not forget to set an `id="UniqueId"` and `runat="server"`.

You can observe the "OnSelected" or "OnDataBinding" events of SqlDataSource and do something like this:

```
private void FeedCountryDropDown(IEnumerable<Country> countries)
{
    if (countries == null || !countries.Any())
        return;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var c in countries)
    {
        sb.Append("<div class=\"item\" data-value=\"")
            .Append(c.Id.ToString())
            .Append("\">")
            .Append(c.Name)
            .Append("</div>");
    }
    countryDropdown.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
}

private void FeedStatesDropDown(IEnumerable<State> states)
{
    if (states == null || !states.Any())
        return;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var s in states)
    {
        sb.Append("<div class=\"item\" data-value=\"")
            .Append(s.Id.ToString())
            .Append("\">")
            .Append(s.Name)
            .Append("</div>");
    }
    stateDropdown.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
}
```

**Dropdownlist Refresh After Ajax operation**

```
<script>
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    $('#dvIDCountryCodeDropdownClone').dropdown();
    $('#dvIDStateCodeDropdownClone').dropdown();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        $('#dvIDCountryCodeDropdownClone').dropdown('refresh');
        $('#dvIDStateCodeDropdownClone').dropdown('refresh');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Henry, It works good for the first time. When I select the other country a second time, it does not work. What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you changing in the semantic dropdown?
When you change, is the postback to the server invoked?

Comment: Yes, I am changing in the semantic dropdown. When I change, the postback is not invoked.

Comment: You're probably misunderstanding asp.net webforms. WebForms simulate states through viewstate engine. The runat="server" say to asp.net webform what save in viewstate and which Html element to transforma into control in the server, that's why i suggest to you, to write runat="server" in my answer.
You need to register an event in the script mananger to force a postback.
See [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) link to know how.

Comment: In [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256129/2738309) answer i give a suggestion to how force a call back.